# How can i change disks from foreign state using OMSA

Tags: windows, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I added 4 disks in the PowerEdge T610 on connector 1 but they are in the foreign state.  I upgraded the firmware to version 6.3.3.0002.  Still, I could not get the function to clear foreign state.

What should I do next to change their state to ready?

Comment: you can check this link, very simple explanation to your issue.
http://www.oxfordsbsguy.com/2016/01/13/dell-perc-how-to-clear-the-foreign-configuration-on-a-hdd-using-the-raid-configuration-utility/#comment-23511 Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The "foreign state" means that the newly inserted disks carry an existing raid configuration (possibly once created on another server).

You may either:

- "clear" this state on each individual disk (this action will destroy data on these disks), or
- "import" this foreign raid configuration (assuming that all disk involved in the raid configuration are present) to recover the whole disk configuration.

Clearing the foreign status in OMSA has been discussed here : http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19299553

Quote :

> To clear foreign configuration:  select the controller on OpenManage, go to the "Information/Configuration" tab, on "Controller Tasks" select "Foreign Configiration Operations", click "Execute".  On the next page, click "Clear"

Comment: Ideally if you can copy paste the relevant commands from the link, that will help avoid link-rot.